# How to connect function to button?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a little contact code for user to input like so:

```
First name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "firstname"><br>
Last name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "lastname"><br>
Email:<br>
    <input type = "email" name = "email"><br>
Text:<br>
    <textarea rows = "10" cols = "50" name = "textbox"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
    <br>
```

and I have this php function to run if fields that user inputs are empty:

```
<?php>
if(!empty($_POST[firstname] && (!empty$_POST[lastname]) && (!empty$_POST[email]) && 
$_POST[textbox]))
{

}
?>
```

My question is how to connect this button "Submit" to this function and how to have a text above it saying "You need to not leave empty fields!" for example?

Comment: `<!php>` that is wrong for one thing, it should read as `<?php`. Plus, you have syntax errors; enable error reporting and you'll see what I mean. I also don't see any form tags.

Comment: So should I try a with javascript somehow or with how do you propose to solve this problem?

Comment: You need a form with a POST method and use the right syntax for the php tag. Your edit `<?php>` one `>` too many. Also quote your arrays. Use `OR` -- `||`  and not `AND` - `&&`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the hint, cheers

Comment: Ideally you need to check on both client and server sides for proper input. You can use the `required`  property in your input fields and do the consistency work in the backend. Put it all inside a form that submits to itself (or another page) and add the PHP code to verify before you display the rest of the page.

Comment: I propose you learn about html forms, namely the `<form>` element. Thereafter you teach yourself how to capture posted data in PHP.  Then you should look into how to check whether a variable exists and has value other null. That should get you going.

Comment: I never used <form> before I think this is the time now, thanks.

Comment: The php provided in this question is silly with breakage. I'm going to assume its an example, poorly written in haste, and not actually any code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing form tags with a post method and a few brackets.

Note: I removed the `!` operator since that means "not", but you can put those back in if you want to use it another way and changing the echo message.

Also, quote the arrays since that could throw a few notices.

This is what your code should look like and using `||` (OR) instead of `&&` (AND) to check if ***any*** are empty.

HTML:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
First name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "firstname"><br>
Last name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "lastname"><br>
Email:<br>
    <input type = "email" name = "email"><br>
Text:<br>
    <textarea rows = "10" cols = "50" name = "textbox"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
    <br>
</form>
```

PHP (handler.php):

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['firstname']) || empty($_POST['lastname']) 
   || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['textbox']))
{
    echo "Some fields were left empty.";
}
?>
```

Side note: You need to run this off a webserver with PHP installed with a server protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) and not directly into your browser as `file:///` since that will not parse any of the PHP directives.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial on forms on PHP.net http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php also.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if($_POST['submit']){
        if( empty($_POST['firstname']) || empty($_POST['lastname']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['textbox']) )
        {
            echo "You need to not leave empty fields!";
        }
    }
?>

<form method="POST">
    First name:<br>
        <input type = "text" name = "firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
        <input type = "text" name = "lastname"><br>
    Email:<br>
        <input type = "email" name = "email"><br>
    Text:<br>
        <textarea rows = "10" cols = "50" name = "textbox"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
        <br>
</form>
```